# How to set the values from Field(Reflection) to POJO?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection

I am working on dynamically mapping values from ResultSet to POJO in java. I am able to get the values but don't know how to set those value to the pojo. Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance !!

```
List<T> results = new ArrayList<>();
    while(resultSet.next())
    {
        T newObj = clazz.newInstance();
        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) 
        {
            String fieldName = field.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (columnNames.containsKey(fieldName)) 
            {
                final int index = columnNames.get(fieldName);
                field.set(fieldName, resultSet.getObject(index+1));
            }
        }
        results.add(newObj);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `Field.set` must be the object, if it is an instance field, or `null` for `static` field. You are passing `fieldName` instead, which is obviously wrong.

So change

```
field.set(fieldName, resultSet.getObject(index+1));
```

to

```
field.set(newObj, resultSet.getObject(index+1));
```

When your code doesn’t have the necessary access rights, it may need to set the “accessible” state on the `Field` object. But generally, you should avoid repeating such expensive operations for every row of the `ResultSet`. So, you may use

```
List<T> results = new ArrayList<>();
Field[] theFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
// if overriding access right is needed:
AccessibleObject.setAccessible(theFields, true);

while(resultSet.next())
{
    T newObj = clazz.newInstance();
    for (Field field: theFields) 
    {
        Integer index = columnNames.get(field.getName().toLowerCase());
        if(index != null)
            field.set(newObj, resultSet.getObject(index+1));
    }
    results.add(newObj);
}
```

instead. Or even

```
List<T> results = new ArrayList<>();
Field[] theFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
// if overriding access right is needed:
AccessibleObject.setAccessible(theFields, true);

int numberOfFields = theFields.length;
int[] columnIndex = new int[numberOfFields];
for(int ix = 0; ix < numberOfFields; ix++) {
    Integer index = columnNames.get(theFields[ix].getName().toLowerCase());
    if(index != null) columnIndex[ix] = index + 1;
}

Constructor<T> con = clazz.getConstructor();

while(resultSet.next())
{
    T newObj = con.newInstance();
    for(int ix = 0; ix < numberOfFields; ix++)
        if(columnIndex[ix] != 0)
            theFields[ix].set(newObj, resultSet.getObject(columnIndex[ix]));
    results.add(newObj);
}
```

which is more complicated in the initialization, but reducing the *repeated* work inside the loop even further. Note that using `Constructor` here is more than an optimization, as starting with Java 9, `Class.newInstance()` has been marked *deprecated*.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below line before setting value?

```
 field.setAccessible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get familiar with [FieldUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html) package from apache commons, exactly with [writeDeclaredField](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html#writeDeclaredField-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
@Test
public void testWriteDeclaredNamedField() {
    FieldUtils.writeDeclaredField(object, "fieldName", "fieldValue");
    assertEquals("fieldValue", FieldUtils.readDeclaredField(object, "fieldName"));
}
```

Comment: @PradeepAnand If my answer was helpful, even more if it solves your problem, please hit upvote button and mark my answer as solution for your question (hit ✓). Thanks